# Python multiple inheritance, initializing from a common subclass

Tags: python

How can I make a common subclass initialize all parent classes it's inheriting from?

```
class Mom(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Mom")

class Dad(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Dad")

class Child(Mom, Dad):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

c = Child() #only prints Mom
```

Comment: This task really doesn't make any sense. Of course, you can call in all inheritance sequence, but still - why you need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are missing the `super()` calls in the `Mom` and `Dad` classes that are required for co-operative subclassing to work.

```
class Mom(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mom, self).__init__()
        print("Mom")

class Dad(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dad, self).__init__()
        print("Dad")

class Child(Dad, Mom):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
c = Child() # Mom, Dad
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `super` in Mom's `__init__` as well.

Comment: Does Dad allow that though?